# Large number of rejected connections in memcached using django

Tags: django, memcached

I'm using Django-4.6.2 with memcached-1.5.22 in Ubuntu-focal (20.04 LTS).

The Django Cache settings (`django.conf.settings.CACHES`) are as follows:

```
 {
   'default': {
       'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyMemcacheCache',
       'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211'
   }
 }
```

memcached is configured to use 1GB of memory (`-m 1024`), uses port 12111 (`-p 11211`), listens to localhost (`-l 127.0.0.1`) and has a maximum object size of 32MB (`-I 32M`).

Despite this, there seem to be a large number of rejected connections in memcached stats (obtained via telnet):

```
STAT max_connections 1024
STAT curr_connections 1
STAT total_connections 2462353
STAT rejected_connections 2462352
STAT connection_structures 11
```

Django is configured with wsgi, with `processes=12`, `threads=12`.

Is this large number of rejected connections normal? What is the likely cause?